# The link/button "Add content set" was disappeared (Drupal6)

Tags: migrations

According to the post http://drupal.org/node/907542, It mentioned [Go to Admin > Content Management > Migrate and click on "Add content set"].

However, I can't find the link/button of "Add content set", I have install migrate module to another test server, but not works. Could someone advise how to fix it?

Thanks

Reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by installing the migrate module of version with 1.x

http://drupal.org/node/966190